# gFlot get color ..when is it attached to DOM in GWT

Tags: gwt, flot

Since color of plotting is fixed after the component is attached to DOM..when can i call the method using GWT? what handler should I implement to come at the right time?

Edit:
The actual context is something like (vp is a VerticalPanel):

```
                plot=createPlotGraph();
                if (plot!=null){
                    plot.setSize("100%","100%");
                    vp.add(plot);
                    vp.setCellHeight(plot, "100%");                     

                    plot.addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {

                       @Override
                        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
                            plot.getModel().getSeries().get(0).getAutoGeneratedColor()
                            System.out.println(plot.getModel().getSeries().length());
                            System.out.println(plot.getModel().getSeries().get(0).getColor());

                       }
                    });
                }
```

and I found i have 3 (or more) series that actually are correctly rendered, i see all ok on screen, but the color wrote down by println is always null.

Other try:

```
      if (plot!=null){
                    plot.setSize("100%","100%");



                    plot.addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {

                            System.out.println(plot.getModel().getSeries().length());
                            System.out.println(plot.getModel().getSeries().get(0).getColor());

                        }
                    });



                    vp.add(plot);
                    vp.setCellHeight(plot, "100%");

                }
```

same result

update, other try:

```
        plot.setSize("100%","100%");



                    plot.addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {

                            Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
                                @Override
                                public void execute() {
                                    System.out.println(plot.getModel().getSeries().length());
                                    System.out.println(plot.getModel().getSeries().get(0).getColor());
                                }
                            });                             
                        }
                    });
```

same result...null

Comment: It looks like you should *first* add the attach handler and then add the plot. Otherwise it's possible that the `AttachEvent` will get fired before you add a handler to handle it...

Comment: Just tried the way you can see in the edit...same result 3 series, null color

Comment: seems the problem is somewhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual solution directly from gFlot forum:

```
plot.getPlot().getData().get(n).getString("color")
```

series are not used directly but copied and color isn't set on the original one!

Hope could be helpful to someone else

Answer (score 0):

You should add an [`AttachEvent.Handler`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/AttachEvent.Handler.html) to your `Widget`:

```java
widget.addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {
    @Override
    public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
        if (event.isAttached()) {
            // Widget got attached to DOM
        } else {
            // Detached
        }
    }
});
```

If you are having problems accessing your JSNI wrappers' values (in this case gflot's), it usually helps to wrap the call in a `ScheduledCommand`. This will ensure that the command will get executed after the browser event loop returns - and that's when your wrapper should be properly initialized in the DOM.

```java
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println(plot.getModel().getSeries().length());
        System.out.println(plot.getModel().getSeries().get(0).getColor());
    }
});
```

Comment: If with widget you mean the gflot instance I already tried but....i have null as result

Comment: Could give more details? What have you tried? Have you followed the instructions on https://github.com/nmorel/gflot/wiki?

Comment: Well I have a GWT SimplePanel that, within an external event (a button event), is the container of my golf. Basically the sequenze is: button--> gflot creation---> add the event handler you suggested on the gflot object...and in the event test series color...obtaining null

Comment: Please update the original question with as much relevant information as possible. Squeezing it into a comment won't help much.